# rsync --delete when destination is remote

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm using a script that pulls and pushes files from my laptop to my server. The command I use to push any changes is this:

```
rsync -Pravtz --delete /home/username/sync/* example.com:/home/username/sync/
```

This works for the most part, but the issue I'm having is that `--delete` does not seem to have an effect. If I delete a file locally, and then try to push, the remote file isn't deleted. Doing a pull works as expected - local files are deleted if no longer present on remote.

Does `--delete` only work on local files, or am I doing something wrong? How do I achieve what I'm trying to do with rsync?

Comment: this might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/476041/how-do-i-make-rsync-delete-files-that-have-been-deleted-from-the-source-folder

Comment: --delete-delay  for remote files

Comment: use either  --delete-before OR --delete-delay  for that effect to take on remote system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue: from rsyncs point of view, I wasn't asking to mirror a directory, but all of the files in said directory. It works as intended after removing an asterisk that shouldn't have been there. My push-script now looks like this:

```
rsync -Pravtz --delete /home/username/sync/ example.com:/home/username/sync/
```